# How to find convergence of fourier series where derivatives don't exist?

Tags: fourier-series

After calculating the fourier series of $$f(x) = \sqrt {\left| x \right|} $$
which is:
$$\frac{2}{3}\sqrt \pi   - \frac{2}{\pi }\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{S(\sqrt {n\pi } )}}{{{n^{1.5}}}}} \cos (nx)$$
where $$ S(x) $$ is Fresnel instegral.
I showed that the series converges at $$x = 0$$
by bounding it.

Now I am trying to calculate the series:
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{S(n\pi )}}{{{n^{1.5}}}}} $$
which is the above fourier series at $$x = 0$$
However ,since the derivatives at $$x = 0$$ aren't finite I am unable to use Dirichlet, and cannot say that it converges to $$f(0)$$

In what way is it possible to find the value of convergenge in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivatives aren't necessary. If $f$ satisfies a Hölder condition, its Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$. If $f$ is of bounded variation, the series converges everywhere. If $f$ is continuous and the Fourier series is absolutely summable, it converges uniformly. All of that is satisfied in your case.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence